# Proof of Euler's Line

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to prove Euler's line without the use of similar triangle theorems? I.e A proof with just using vectors?

I am able to prove using similar triangle theorems, but would like to see if Euler's line can be proved without the use of it and using just vectors instead?

Comment: For a starting point: [Euler line - A vector proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line#A_vector_proof). (Did you even try to google the title of your question?)

Comment: What is the reason for looking at a convoluted proof, when the usual proof through similarities is straightforward and three lines long? Just as a curiosity, no offense intended.

Answer (score 2):

Let we consider a triangle $ABC$, and let we take its circumcenter $O$ as the origin of a reference system. From now on, I will just use $A$ to denote the vector $\vec{OA}$. Let $G$ be the centroid of $ABC$.
It fulfills $G=\frac{A+B+C}{3}$. Let we define $U$ as $A+B+C$. We may notice that

$$\langle U-C,A-B \rangle = \langle A+B,A-B\rangle = \|A\|^2-\|B\|^2 = R^2-R^2=0, $$
so the line joining $C$ and $U$ is perpendicular to the $AB$-side. In a similar way, the line joining $U$ and $B$ is perpendicular to the $AC$-side, hence $U\equiv H$ ($U$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$) and
$$ H=3G=A+B+C.$$