# Orthocentre Geometry Proof

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I need help with the following geometry problem:

> Let $O$ be the centre of circumscribed circle of $\Delta ABC$ and $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$ be the vectors pointing from $O$ to their vertices.
>
> Let $M$ be the endpoint of $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}$ measured from $O$.
>
> Prove that $M$ is the orthocentre of $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: The centroid $G$ is given by $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$, and by Euler's theorem $O,G,H$ are collinear and $\frac{HO}{GO}=3$.

Comment: I don't think I can use Euler's theorem since the next problem asked me to prove that.

Comment: In such a case, have a look at here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947191/proof-of-eulers-line/1947361#1947361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that $O'$ is orthocenter iff $$ (O'-c )\cdot (a-b)=0 \ \ast$$
>   for $c$ and for $a,\ b$ corresponded equation wrt $\ast$ hold

Note that if $H=a+b+c$, then $$(H-c) \cdot (a-b)=|a|^2-|b|^2=0$$
That is $H=O'$

Comment: Aren't you using what is meant to prove, namely that $H=a+b+c$?

Comment: Maybe it is better to write it as *let we define a point $U$ as $a+b+c$. Since $(U-c)\cdot(a-b)=0$ and so on, it follows that $U\equiv H$.*